# Disable is Required Field Validator is not check in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Please how can I disable the required field validator is the check box is check.

Below is the code to the text box and required field validator.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="business_owner_CheckBox" runat="server">
 <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="false">I am a business owner</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>


<asp:TextBox ID="business_name_Textbox" runat="server" CssClass="login-form-control col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" 
placeholder="Business Name"></asp:TextBox>


<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="business_name_Textbox" 
ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: did you tried anything, atleast google it..

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1175267.aspx

Comment: This is web forms, not MVC

Comment: @nadeem i have tried oVal = document.getElementById("<%=RequiredFieldValidator3.ClientID %>");

    ValidatorEnable(oVal, false);       but i keep getting The name 'RequiredFieldValidator3' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @stevo: you have given wrong syntax in js, the correct **ID** is `("#<%= RequiredFieldValidator3.ClientID %>");`. In your syntax **#** is missing